# Hue Query Impala Editor Theme Settings?

Tags: hive, impala, hue

I am new to working in HUE Hive/Impala environment.  My current environment looks like this:

[image]

It's just very washed out/white/bright and painful to stare at.  I'm not sure if there is even row banding or not (appears not).  Also no grid results with all four lines in grid.

I'm a 'dark theme' kinda guy and have searched high and low for ways to adjust the theme/colors/etc.... and just come up with nothing.

Is it possible to adjust the appearance of this or not?

Answer (score 1):

How about the new Dark Them in 4.3? http://gethue.com/additional-sql-improvements-in-hue-4-3/

Answer (score 1):

To toggle the dark mode you can either press Ctrl-Alt-T or Command-Option-T on Mac while the editor has focus. Alternatively you can control this through the settings menu which is shown by pressing Ctrl-, or Command-, on Mac